# SQL Server - Pivot - Rows into column for multiple varchar columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Input data

[image]

Need to pivot data based on ID. And required output as below:

Output required

[image]

Need suitable solution which will give efficient output.

Adding text as alternative for image :

Input data:

```
+---+----+-------+------+------ +---------+-------+

|ID |Q_NO| SUB_CD|PR_TX |C_TX   |AD_DTL_TX|  B_NM |

+---+----+-------+------+------ +---------+-------+
|111|   1|  A   |asd    |sdf    |qwerwet  |qqwe   |
|111|   1|  B   |ger    |sdt    |uutty    |  ttt  |
|112|   1|  B   |yut    |www    |yyjy     | y     |
|114|   1|  A   |atd    |stf    |qwwet    |qe     |
|114|   1|  B   |atw    |rf     |qwet     |qwp    |
|114|   2|  A   |aq     |yf     |qyet     |qoe    |
|117|   1|  A   |aee    |yrr    |qyet     |qoe    |
|117|   2|  A   |tq     |uf     |et       |oe     |
+---+----+-------+------+------ +---------+-------+
```

Required Output:

```
+---+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+

|ID |Q_NO_1A    |SUB_CD_1A| PR_TX_1A|C_TX_1A    |AD_DTL_TX_1A|  B_NM_1A|    Q_NO_1B|    SUB_CD_1B|  PR_TX_1B    |C_TX_1B    |AD_DTL_TX_1B|B_NM_1B|  Q_NO_2A |SUB_CD_2A| PR_TX_2A    |C_TX_2A    |AD_DTL_TX_2A|  B_NM_2A|
+---+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|111|   yes     |   yes   |    asd  |    sdf    |     qwerwet|     qqwe|        yes|          yes|        ger   |     sdt   |     uutty  |   ttt |    null  |    null |    null     |      null |      null  |    null |
|112|   null    |  null   |   null  |   null    |      null  |null     |yes        |      yes    |         yut  |      www  |        yyj |y      |    null  |  null   |    null     |null       |       null |null     |
|114|   yes     |   yes   |  atd    |   stf     |     qwwet  |   qe    |    yes    |      yes    |      atw     |      rf   |       qwe  |   qwp |    yes   |     yes |      aq     |     yf    |    qyet    |qoe      |
|117|   yes     |   yes   |  aee    |yrr        |   qyet     |     qoe |    null   |    null     |      null    |    null   |    null    |   null|   yes    |    yes  |      tq     |       uf  |      et    |  oe     |
+---+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Most us want sample data as well formatted text instead of as pictures.

Comment: Please format your **Required output**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of unions and a pivot.

```
select * 
from
(
  select id, concat('Q_NO_', q_no, sub_cd) as title, 'yes' as value from YourTable
  union all
  select id, concat('SUB_CD_', q_no, sub_cd) as title, 'yes' as value from YourTable
  union all
  select id, concat('PR_TX_', q_no, sub_cd) as title, pr_tx as value from YourTable
  union all
  select id, concat('C_TX_', q_no, sub_cd) as title, c_tx as value from YourTable
  union all
  select id, concat('AD_DTL_', q_no, sub_cd) as title, ad_dtl_tx as value from YourTable
  union all
  select id, concat('B_NM_', q_no, sub_cd) as title, b_nm as value from YourTable
) q
pivot (max(value) FOR title IN (
  [Q_NO_1A],[SUB_CD_1A],[PR_TX_1A],[C_TX_1A],[AD_DTL_1A],[B_NM_1A],
  [Q_NO_1B],[SUB_CD_1B],[PR_TX_1B],[C_TX_1B],[AD_DTL_1B],[B_NM_1B],
  [Q_NO_2A],[SUB_CD_2A],[PR_TX_2A],[C_TX_2A],[AD_DTL_2A],[B_NM_2A]
  )
) pvt;
```